# Cant restore my back up of windows 7 after formatting the disk because of a major crash

Tags: backup, restore

i backed up my windows 7 to an external hard drive and about a month later windows crashed so i had to format the drive to get thru all the left over junk. then when i put the cd restore disk i made with it it wont reinstall the windows program. i can access the harddrive and all of the file but when i click on the restore folder i just opens to the files i have went thru all of the files for several days selecting them and i keep gettin the same message. not recognized. so i put the drive on another working computer and clicked on the file and it immediatly said would you like to restore your system. so i know the backup is good i the went on the net and i found a page that said i had to manually type in the drive and directory and what not but it wont let me do that either      any suggestions to my problem?
getting very frustrated and ready to take it to the hock shop.

Comment: I would highly suggest you to edit the question of yours as I have had a very difficult time understanding the language. Wait. Did you use Google Translate?!

Comment: What did you use to back up your data? Windows 7's own in-built backup utility?